# How do I enable the cscfg overrides to work with NServiceBus Azure configuration

Tags: azure, nservicebus, azureservicebus, azure-configuration

When using NServiceBus the Transport connection string doesn't seem to be fetched from the applicable Cloud configuration first but immediately from the app.config.

## Options I've tried:

### Using the configuration section (:

cscfg

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="AzureServiceBusQueueConfig.ConnectionString" value="Endpoint=sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=yyy" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

app.config

```
<AzureServiceBusQueueConfig ConnectionString="Endpoint=sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=yyy" />
```

### Using a custom connection string name:

cscfg

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="NServiceBus.Transport" value="Endpoint=sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=yyy" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NServiceBus.Transport" connectionString="Endpoint=sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=yyy"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Also tried to override it by using the following line of code, since this issue is still open (https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.AzureServiceBus/issues/20):

```
configuration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>().ConnectionString(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureServiceBusQueueConfig.ConnectionString"));
```

Or tried to set the connection string name manually, which works again using the app.config but doesn't let the cscfg override.

```
configuration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>().ConnectionStringName("NServiceBus.Transport");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you turn the azure configuration source on? You can do so using following extension method on the bus configuration:

.AzureConfigurationSource()

Comment: Sweet, thanks! For some reason the whole NServiceBus.Azure package wasn't included and obviously this also wasn't configured.